# Applying an active class based on radio button select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm so stuck and frustrated applying an active class to the parent element of a radio box based on click. It works great on the desktop but iOS and mobile devices don't recognize it properly and the class doesn't seem to be getting added.

===== First try ======

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.legal-category-select').find('input:checked').parents('.radio').addClass("active");
    $('.legal-category-select').find('.radio').on('click',function(){
      $('.legal-category-select').find('.radio').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

===== Another try ======

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.legal-category-select').find('input:checked').parents('.radio').addClass("active");
});
$(document).on('change','.legal-category-select',function(){ 
    $('.legal-category-select').find('.radio').removeClass('active');
    $('.legal-category-select').find('input:checked').parent().parent().addClass("active");
});
```

You can see the staging site here: http://michaelwood.ca/work/dh/legal-faqs/

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `touchstart` for iphone support

```
$('.legal-category-select').find('.radio').on('click touchstart',function(){
```